# "x connection host broken" on remote swing application

Tags: java, swing, crash, x11, jvm-crash

My system:
I have a java swing application that is running on Solaris 10/X86 machine without a monitor. I have another machine(Linux/x86) where Im displaying the application via X11.

My problem:
My application runs on 30 machines, 24/7. Sometimes the jvm crashes with the error "X connection  host broken.". I have applications that are running for weeks and never crashed,others that crashed after 1 day once and others that crashes every week. Quite random.

What have i done/checked:
I/O is quite similar on all applications, its a bit network intense but nothing excessive. Memory, cpu and disk usage are similar too. Some machines are used more then others, but no relation with the crashes. The X on the Linux/x86 never crashed. Network seems ok, checked the switches and netstat.

I added SignalHandlers but couldnt find anything. Checked for memory leak and other application problems, but couldnt find anything.

What i need:
1) How can i investigate further? How can i find why the x connection breaks?
2) How can i make my application "X11 crash" proof? It is possible?! To recconect or something?
3) Is there a common reason for this 'connection broken' problem? Or any common solution? (no, i cant run headless =))

Of course jvm didnt generate any core for me =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X11 usually runs over a TCP/IP connection; if that connection breaks for any reason (network down, DHCP change of address, etc) you will lose the X connection.   If the server has permissions (host) to the client display, you could conceivably just open up a new display connection, but if the client has opened a terminal session to the server to launch the app, you likely lost your terminal session as well with the network interruption.

Comment: By 'server' you mean the computer where the application is running, right? Anyway, my problem is that my application ends. JVM calls exit() when the X connection breaks. And I call the application from the server, i set the DISPLAY variable to the other machine and launch the application.

Comment: Yes, I mean server in the X11 sense, i.e. where the application is running.  The client is where the application is *displaying*.  Since you're launching from the server with permissions on the client display, you're in a position to reconnect automatically in the face of a disconnect.  Do you need to keep the application alive, or would it be OK simply to restart it (the latter being eminently easier to implement than the former)?

Comment: Need to keep the application alive. It is possible?

Comment: Might be, I don't recall exactly how Java handles the X11 exceptions; if you could catch the error you could certainly re-init UI after a short pause.  You might be better off making the headless machine use a frame buffer and access that from your client machine via vnc.  That way you could connect/disconnect at will from your administrating machine without disrupting the running application.

Comment: Can't catch the error, but I will try the vnc option. Thanks! Will post back if it worked.